# Parsing date. Can not parse the same format in java

Tags: java, string, date, parsing

I am parsing date from a .csv file which contains date, close price, volume etc.

```
   SimpleDateFormat  sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");

   for(int i = 0; i<pastModel.getRowCount(); i++){

       if(pastModel.getValueAt(i, 0) != null ){

           myDate = sdf.parse(pastModel.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());


       s1.addOrUpdate(new Day(myDate), std.change(pastModel.getValueAt(i, 4).toString()));

       }

   }
```

My csv file contains the below data.

```
5-May-17,2.60,2.64,2.60,2.61,830666

4-May-17,2.62,2.64,2.59,2.59,1204889

3-May-17,2.63,2.65,2.61,2.62,917924

2-May-17,2.69,2.69,2.62,2.62,1386661

28-Apr-17,2.69,2.72,2.68,2.69,1503999

27-Apr-17,2.71,2.73,2.68,2.69,1688354

26-Apr-17,2.71,2.75,2.69,2.70,5044999

25-Apr-17,2.67,2.72,2.66,2.70,4989761

24-Apr-17,2.68,2.69,2.66,2.66,1341020

21-Apr-17,2.67,2.68,2.63,2.64,1177714
```

I can parse the dates till the 28 april but when I come to 28-Apr-17  I got the below output. All the date formats are same in the csv file but I dont know why I got this eror.

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "28-Apr-17"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
at bistx.Bistx.createDataset(Bistx.java:1331)
at bistx.Bistx.chart(Bistx.java:1213)
at bistx.Bistx.runChart(Bistx.java:1349)
at bistx.Bistx$13.actionPerformed(Bistx.java:655)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Try to provide a US locale to the SimpleDateFormat constructor. By default it will use the default locale which may not be English.

Comment: You should ideally be using `java.time` libraries

Comment: Turkish locale? Where the abbreviation for May is May (as in English), but for April is Nis (for Nisan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `Locale` format to `SimpleDateFormat` parameterized constructor.

So, the code would be as below if I add `US` locale.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.US);
```

And this is what I found in javadocs of `SimpleDateFormat` for adding locale to its constructor.

> /**
>        * Constructs a `SimpleDateFormat` using the given pattern and
>        * the default date format symbols for the default
>        * {@link java.util.Locale.Category#FORMAT FORMAT} locale.
>        * **Note:** This constructor may not support all locales.
>        * For full coverage, use the factory methods in the {@link DateFormat}
>        * class.
>        *
>
> This is equivalent to calling
>        * {@link #SimpleDateFormat(String, Locale)
>        *     SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT))}.
>        *
>        * @see java.util.Locale#getDefault(java.util.Locale.Category)
>        * @see java.util.Locale.Category#FORMAT
>        * @param pattern the pattern describing the date and time format
>        * @exception NullPointerException if the given pattern is null
>        * @exception IllegalArgumentException if the given pattern is invalid
>        */
>       public SimpleDateFormat(String pattern)
>       {
>           this(pattern, Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT));
>       }

Hope, this helps!

Comment: Glad to know that it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add the locale to your `SimpleDateFormat`, like this:

`SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.US);`